# Why won't php read my php.ini file?

Tags: php, configuration, ini

There are many questions like this, but I haven't found one that explains this behavior. I'll try to address things covered in similar questions as I go:

I installed php 5.3.28 from source and copied php.ini-production from the source to /usr/local/etc/php53/php.ini. I used the following configure options so that PHP would read that file.

```
# Rearranged for readability
Configure Command =>  './configure'  
                  '--with-config-file-path=/usr/local/etc/php53' 
                  '--with-config-file-scan-dir=/usr/local/etc/php53/conf.d'
                  '--prefix=/usr/local' 
                  '--enable-debug' '--enable-mbstring' '--enable-soap' '--enable-zip' '--with-bz2' '--with-curl' '--with-gettext' '--with-mcrypt' '--with-mhash' '--with-mysql' '--with-openssl' '--with-pdo-mysql' '--with-pspell' '--with-readline' '--with-tidy' '--with-xsl'
```

Well, PHP doesn't read that file.

```
$ php -i | grep Configuration' File'
Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /usr/local/etc/php53
Loaded Configuration File => (none)
$ php --ini
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /usr/local/lib
Loaded Configuration File:         (none)
Scan for additional .ini files in: (none)
Additional .ini files parsed:      (none)
```

How can it be that `php -i` and `php --ini` have different output for *Configuration File (php.ini) Path*?

(Some answers/comments to similar questions want to know which `php` command is in use. It's important to note that this issue is with `php` on the commandline, so the `php` above is the only one. Whether or not Apache is using a different `php` is not relevant in this case.)

I do not have [any php environment variables](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18157969/418413) set:

```
$ env | grep PHP
$ export | grep -iF php
$ set | grep -iF php
```

There is no output for any of the above.

Finally, [I can force](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18157969/418413) `php` to do what I want via a commandline flag (evidence that php can read and parse the file)

```
$ php -nc /usr/local/etc/php53/php.ini -i | grep -F Configuration' Fi'
Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /usr/local/etc/php53
Loaded Configuration File => /usr/local/etc/php53/php.ini
$ php -nc /usr/local/etc/php53/php.ini --ini
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /usr/local/lib
Loaded Configuration File:         /usr/local/etc/php53/php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: (none)
Additional .ini files parsed:      (none)
```

But why does it not load the file I specified to `configure` when I don't give it any flags on the commandline?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP Command Line php.ini path error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5132978/php-command-line-php-ini-path-error)

Comment: It's not a dupe. That question addresses neither the discrepancy between --ini and -i, nor the explicit build time configuration option. Furthermore, the configuration file path output by -i here is correct. In the other question it's not.